# Tutorial de usabilidade com transparência c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou trabalhando com c# e preciso fazer um tutorial de usabilidade, assim como em jogos que escurecem a tela, destacam um componente e exibem uma dica logo abaixo.

Até o momento fiz um Form em cima do outro, pois não consegui fazer uma layer sem que ela interferisse no sistema, pois alterei umas configurações do windows.

Enfim basicamente ficou assim acima do FormMain um form2 com 50% transparente (com 3 painéis que calculo a área de cada na mão para que destaquem um componente especifico que está no FormMain) e acima desse, um terceiro form com um painel contendo a tal dica. Achei essa forma muito ruim, mas não achei outra alternativa, pois não achei nenhuma API ou semelhante que realize esse procedimento.

Comment: estou fazendo um Form que atende a essa sua necessidade, a noite vou posta-lo pra você

Comment: Podes usar um tooltip, é mais simples.

Comment: @gato Se pudesse utilizaria, mas o cliente quer uma tela de tutorial...

Comment: No aguardo @RovannLinhalis !

Comment: Algum retorno @GabrielMonteirodeOliveira ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis realizei alguns testes e parece funcionar, esqueci de comentar que esta dica em que precisamos exibir na verdade seria uma imagem .png ou .gif, e isto não parece funcionar muito bem, mas gostei da sua ideia de colocar um toolTip, vou sugerir está ideia...

Comment: é, não havia nada específicado sobre como a dica seria exibida, então fiz no tool tip, mas é fácil de colocar imagens, se quiser, podemos incrementar isso aí

Comment: @RovannLinhalis se for simples, por favor mostre como funciona ficarei muito grato!

Comment: @GabrielMonteirodeOliveira tem alguma imagem de exemplo que eu possa ter uma ídeia do q precisa ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis seria algo como http://www.superdownloads.com.br/imagens/screenshots/9/0/90972,O.jpg agradeço pela sua ajuda!

Comment: vc vai ter um personagem e um balão como se ele estivesse falando, é isso ?

Comment: Isto mesmo @RovannLinhalis

Comment: Ok, assim que fizer posto aqui o resultado, mas se quiser se adiantar aí, o código vai ser praticamente o mesmo onde se cria o painelTransparente, porém colocando um PictureBox

Comment: @RovannLinhalis eu imaginei que fosse a mesma coisa, mas quando adiciono uma PictureBox no painelTransparente a imagem fica transparente e não sei como resolver...

Comment: Editei minha resposta. veja como ficou

Comment: @RovannLinhalis muito obrigado, isto vai atender muito bem as minhas necessidades!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como havia comentado, estava desenvolvendo um Form que atende a sua necessidade.

Segue o código comentado:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Testes
{
    //Form para destaques de controles
    //Utilizar para Condução do usuário, dicas, etc
    //Dev Rovann Linhalis - 22/06/2017
    public partial class FormHighlightControl : Form
    {
        //Controle que deve ser destacado
        Control ControleDestaque { get; set; }
        //Mensagem que será exibida
        string MensagemDica { get; set; }
        //Form Pai onde está o controle a ser exibido
        Form FormPai { get; set; }
        //Painel que será transparente
        Panel PainelTransparente { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Form de destaque de controles e exibição de dicas
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="_parent">Form que será escurecido</param>
        /// <param name="_control">Controle que será destacado</param>
        /// <param name="_message">Mensagem de dica</param>
        /// <param name="_opacity">Transparencia do Form, 0=Invisivel, 1=Visivel, Recomendado 0.4</param>
        public FormHighlightControl(Form _parent, Control _control, string _message, double _opacity)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Define a chave de transparencia do form
            this.TransparencyKey = Color.Magenta;
            //Define a cor do sombreamento do form
            this.BackColor = Color.Black;
            //Atribuição dos valores passados por parametro
            this.FormPai = _parent;
            this.Opacity = _opacity;
            this.ControleDestaque = _control;
            this.MensagemDica = _message;
            //Define visual do form
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.Size = this.FormPai.Size;
            this.Location = this.FormPai.Location;

            //Fechar com ESC
            this.KeyPreview = true;
            this.KeyDown += FormHighlightControl_KeyDown;
        }

        //Fechar com ESC
        void FormHighlightControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Escape)
                this.Close();
        }

        //Ao carregar o form, monta o painel transparente
        private void FormHighlightControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PainelTransparente = new Panel();
            PainelTransparente.Size = ControleDestaque.Size;
            PainelTransparente.BackColor = Color.Magenta;
            Rectangle r = FormPai.RectangleToScreen(FormPai.ClientRectangle);
            PainelTransparente.Location = new Point(ControleDestaque.Location.X + SystemInformation.SizingBorderWidth + r.Left - FormPai.Left, ControleDestaque.Location.Y + r.Top - FormPai.Top);
            PainelTransparente.Parent = this;
        }

        //Ao exibir o Form, Mostra a dica
        protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnShown(e);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.MensagemDica))
            {
                toolTip1.ToolTipTitle = "Dica";
                toolTip1.ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
                toolTip1.IsBalloon = true;
                toolTip1.OwnerDraw = true;
                toolTip1.SetToolTip(PainelTransparente, MensagemDica);
                toolTip1.Show(MensagemDica, PainelTransparente, PainelTransparente.Size.Width, PainelTransparente.Size.Height, 10000);
            }
        }
        //Fechar form ao clicar com o mouse em qlqr lugar
        private void FormHighlightControl_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }



    }
}
```

Agora, sempre que quiser destacar um controle, e exibir um texto como dica, faça a chamada do Form assim:

```
        private void buttonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormHighlightControl form = new FormHighlightControl(this, buttonOk, "Este é o botão OK!", .4);
            form.ShowDialog();

        }
```

Resultado:
[image: Resultado do Form]

ps. Várias opções podem ser definidas pela interface do visual studio, preferi colocá-las dentro do construtor para melhor entendimento de quem utilizar o código.

**Edit**

Após pensar melhor nas necessidades, decidi criar uma classe para controlar as dicas que serão exibidas:

```
public class HighLightHint
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Título a ser exibido na dica
    /// </summary>
    public string Title { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Texto da dica
    /// </summary>
    public string Mensagem { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Controle ao qual a dica é atribuida
    /// </summary>
    public Control Control { get; set; }
}
```

Feito isso, agora no Form, você pode adicionar várias dicas, além de uma imagem de assistente. Segue código do Form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Testes
{
//Form para destaques de controles
//Utilizar para Condução do usuário, dicas, etc
//Dev Rovann Linhalis - 28/06/2017
public partial class FormHighlightControl : Form
{
    //Painel que será transparente
    Panel PainelTransparente { get; set; }
    //Form que será exibido o assistente
    Form PicAssistente { get; set; }
    //índice da dica exibida
    int HintIndex;
    //Form Pai onde está o controle a ser exibido
    public Form FormPai { get; set; }

    ToolTip toolTip1;

    /// <summary>
    /// Lista de Dicas
    /// </summary>
    public List<HighLightHint> Lista { get; set; }
    //Imagem do assistente (usar png com fundo transparente)
    public Image Assistente { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Form de destaque de controles e exibição de dicas
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_parent">Form que será escurecido</param>
    /// <param name="_control">Controle que será destacado</param>
    /// <param name="_message">Mensagem de dica</param>
    /// <param name="_opacity">Transparencia do Form, 0=Invisivel, 1=Visivel, Recomendado 0.4</param>
    public FormHighlightControl(Form _parent, double _opacity, List<HighLightHint> _lista)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        HintIndex = -1;
        //Define a chave de transparencia do form
        this.TransparencyKey = Color.Magenta;
        //Define a cor do sombreamento do form
        this.AllowTransparency = true;
        this.BackColor =Color.Black;
        //Atribuição dos valores passados por parametro
        this.FormPai = _parent;
        this.Opacity = _opacity;

        //Define visual do form
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.Size = this.FormPai.Size;
        this.Location = this.FormPai.Location;
        this.Lista = _lista;
        //Fechar com ESC
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.KeyDown += FormHighlightControl_KeyDown;

    }

    public FormHighlightControl(Form _parent, double _opacity , List<HighLightHint> _lista, Image _assistente) : this(_parent, _opacity, _lista)
    {
        this.Assistente = _assistente;
    }

    //Fechar com ESC
    void FormHighlightControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Close();
            if (PicAssistente != null && !PicAssistente.IsDisposed)
                PicAssistente.Close();
        }
    }

    private void MostrarDica(int index)
    {
        if (this.Lista.Count > index)
        {
            this.Invalidate();

            if (toolTip1 != null)
                toolTip1.RemoveAll();

            toolTip1 = new ToolTip();

            if (PainelTransparente == null)
                PainelTransparente = new Panel();

            toolTip1.RemoveAll();
            if (PicAssistente != null && !PicAssistente.IsDisposed)
                PicAssistente.Close();

            Rectangle r = FormPai.RectangleToScreen(FormPai.ClientRectangle);
            Point newLocation = new Point(this.Lista[index].Control.Location.X + SystemInformation.SizingBorderWidth + r.Left - FormPai.Left, this.Lista[index].Control.Location.Y + r.Top - FormPai.Top);

            PainelTransparente.Size = this.Lista[index].Control.Size;
            PainelTransparente.BackColor = Color.Magenta;

            PainelTransparente.Location = newLocation;
            PainelTransparente.Parent = this;

            if (Assistente != null)
            {
                if (PicAssistente == null || PicAssistente.IsDisposed)
                {
                    PicAssistente = new Form();
                }

                PicAssistente.TopMost = true;
                PicAssistente.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
                PicAssistente.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                PicAssistente.BackColor = Color.Magenta;
                PicAssistente.TransparencyKey = Color.Magenta;
                PicAssistente.AllowTransparency = true;
                PicAssistente.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
                PicAssistente.Size = new Size(150, 200);

                if (newLocation.X > this.Width/2)
                {
                    if (newLocation.Y > this.Height / 2)
                    {
                        PicAssistente.Location = new Point(this.Location.X - this.Lista[index].Control.Width + this.Lista[index].Control.Location.X + SystemInformation.SizingBorderWidth + r.Left - FormPai.Left, this.Location.Y - PicAssistente.Height + this.Lista[index].Control.Location.Y + r.Top - FormPai.Top);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PicAssistente.Location = new Point(this.Location.X - this.Lista[index].Control.Width + this.Lista[index].Control.Location.X + SystemInformation.SizingBorderWidth + r.Left - FormPai.Left, this.Location.Y + this.Lista[index].Control.Location.Y + r.Top - FormPai.Top);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (newLocation.Y > this.Height / 2)
                    {
                        PicAssistente.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + this.Lista[index].Control.Width + this.Lista[index].Control.Location.X + SystemInformation.SizingBorderWidth + r.Left - FormPai.Left, this.Location.Y - PicAssistente.Height + this.Lista[index].Control.Location.Y + r.Top - FormPai.Top);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PicAssistente.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + this.Lista[index].Control.Width+ this.Lista[index].Control.Location.X + SystemInformation.SizingBorderWidth + r.Left - FormPai.Left, this.Location.Y + this.Lista[index].Control.Location.Y + r.Top - FormPai.Top);
                    }
                }

                PicAssistente.BackgroundImage = Assistente;
                //PicAssistente.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 0, 0, 0);
                PicAssistente.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
                PicAssistente.Show();

            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Lista[index].Mensagem))
            {


                toolTip1.ToolTipTitle = this.Lista[index].Title;
                toolTip1.ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
                toolTip1.IsBalloon = true;
                toolTip1.OwnerDraw = true;
                if (PicAssistente != null)
                {
                    toolTip1.SetToolTip(PicAssistente, this.Lista[index].Mensagem);
                    toolTip1.Show(this.Lista[index].Mensagem, PicAssistente, PicAssistente.Width/2, 0, 10000);
                }
                else
                {
                    toolTip1.SetToolTip(PainelTransparente, this.Lista[index].Mensagem);
                    toolTip1.Show(this.Lista[index].Mensagem, PainelTransparente, PainelTransparente.Size.Width, PainelTransparente.Size.Height, 10000);
                }
            }


        }
        else
        {
            this.Close();
            if (PicAssistente != null && !PicAssistente.IsDisposed)
                PicAssistente.Close();
        }
    }

    //Ao exibir o Form, Mostra a dica
    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnShown(e);
        MostrarDica(++HintIndex);
    }
    //Fechar form ao clicar com o mouse em qlqr lugar
    private void FormHighlightControl_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MostrarDica(++HintIndex);
    }



}
}
```

E enfim, a chamada do Form:

```
 private void buttonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        List<HighLightHint > listaDicas = new List<HighLightHint>();
        listaDicas.Add(new HighLightHint() { Control = listBox1, Mensagem = "Este é o ListBox1!", Title = "Titulo dica 1" });
        listaDicas.Add(new HighLightHint() { Control = listBox2, Mensagem = "Este é o ListBox2!", Title = "Titulo dica 2" });
        listaDicas.Add(new HighLightHint() { Control = listBox3, Mensagem = "Este é o ListBox3!", Title = "Titulo dica 3" });
        listaDicas.Add(new HighLightHint() { Control = buttonOk, Mensagem = "Este é o buttonOK!", Title = "Titulo dica 4" });



        FormHighlightControl form = new FormHighlightControl(this,.4, listaDicas , global::Testes.Properties.Resources.wizard_magician_conjure_conjurer_icon_icons_com_53580);
        form.ShowDialog();

}
```

Não tenho muito tempo, mas achei bacana o proposito. Veja se te ajuda.